# Folland's real analysis, theorem 5.24

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

In Folland's proof of theorem 5.24, he states

[image]
[image]

May I ask why the highlighted claim is correct without loss of generality? If $u \in \mathcal{M}$, why multiplying $u$ by a nonzero scalar make $\langle z,u \rangle$ a real?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The claim is not that multiplying $u$ by *any* non-zero scalar will make $\langle z, u \rangle$ real. It is simply saying that for any $u, z$ one can find $c \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\langle z, c u\rangle$ is real. Does that clarify the issue?

Comment: @Peter Got it. Thank you very much!